# show div after event on bigger and smaller devices

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that i want to hide on smaller devices and show them only after a movie came to the end.
on bigger devices i want to show this div regardless of the movie.

so what i did is to give this div `display: none` at line 1 and

```
@media (min-width: 900px){
  .movie_box{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

and on my code, after the movie is done:

```
$('.movie_box').show();
```

That works fine on smaller devices and i can see this div at the end of the movie.

On bigger devices, when this div is already shown, seems like the code isn't working because when i scroll down the screen size i can't see this div. the `display: none` stay.

Comment: I don't get it: you say "On bigger devices, when this div is already shown" but then you add "when i scroll down the screen size i can't see this div"

Comment: sounds like you want this div to be **position:fixed**?

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff - The div is shown on bigger devices, but on smaller devices it will show only after the movie end. so if i'm on big screen size and the movie end, i change the screen width, the div is not shown even if the movie ended.

Answer (score 1):

Change your media queries to:

**CSS:**

```
.movie_box{
    display: none; // this will hide div for each screen sizes
}

@media (min-width: 900px){
  .movie_box.unhidden{
    display: block; // this shows div for big sizes 
                    //but only when it have .unhidden class
  }
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.movie_box').addClass('unhidden'); // this will add unhidden class after movie will end
```

Comment: That's working the same. anyway, if i'm on big screen size and scroll to small screen size i still can't see this div even if the movie end.

Comment: Perfect! didn't thought about giving new class. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Using show() was wrong idea in this special case. It's sometimes good practice to add class to for example <body> element and control whole enviroment with it